# Okta SSO Integration for A Custom OIDC App

Tags: single-sign-on, integration, openid-connect, okta, custom-application

We are looking to set up our application to support Okta SSO.

The steps we've taken so far:

- signed up for Okta developer account and created an app and an org
- integrated our frontend react app with the created Okta app and Okta sign-in page for sign in
- the frontend app sends the user tokens and claims from Okta to the backend django app
- the backend verifies them with Okta and respond to the frontend with our own JWT tokens to use for subsequent requests
- we've been able to add users to our own org to log in, but we have a client from another org that has an Okta SSO subscription, if we want to set them up to log into our application using SSO, what would be the steps we need to take?
- OIN takes quite a long time to review a submission, are there any alternatives to satisfy our use case and if so what are the steps we should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

You need their Okta Admins to create an OIDC application(s) in their Okta tenant with the callback URLs of your app.

This thought would make your application single tenant, unless you made certain efforts to make it multitenant. So that your next customer coming and registering your application in their Okta tenant and thus producing another client_id/issuer pair, will be able to go to the same physical instance of your app.